# Why can I rename @BindingAdapter("app:popularityIcon") without error when I use databing in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack

The Code A and Code B are from the project https://github.com/android/databinding-samples.

The Code B display an icon based `fun popularityIcon(view: ImageView, popularity: Popularity)` and works well.

I find that project can still work well even if I rename  `@BindingAdapter("app:popularityIcon")` to  `@BindingAdapter("myok:popularityIcon")`, just like Code C, why?

**Code A**

```
object BindingAdapters {    
    @BindingAdapter("app:popularityIcon")
    @JvmStatic fun popularityIcon(view: ImageView, popularity: Popularity) {
        val color = getAssociatedColor(popularity, view.context)
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(view, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
        view.setImageDrawable(getDrawablePopularity(popularity, view.context))
    }
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/profile_avatar_cd"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/likes_label"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:popularityIcon="@{viewmodel.popularity}"/>
```

**Code C**

```
object BindingAdapters {    
    @BindingAdapter("myok:popularityIcon")
    @JvmStatic fun popularityIcon(view: ImageView, popularity: Popularity) {
        val color = getAssociatedColor(popularity, view.context)
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(view, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
        view.setImageDrawable(getDrawablePopularity(popularity, view.context))
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databinding ignores namespaces. So it removes `app:` or `myok:` or anything else. Also, if you put both adapters with the same name but different namespaces, you would get an error telling you that there are more than one adapter for `popularityIcon`.
You can check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for more information.

> Note: The Data Binding Library ignores custom namespaces for matching purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your namespace in your XML were you using this binding.
like below

```
xmlns:myok="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

check below code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myok="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry that I can't understand what you mean.  I think that the app will crash when I rename `@BindingAdapter("app:popularityIcon")` to `@BindingAdapter("myok:popularityIcon")`, but the app can work well after  rename, why?